# htaccess to web.config file rewriteCond

Tags: mod-rewrite, web-config

I have this htaccess wich gets the folder added in the url and converts it into a variable. As follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1
```

I had to convert it to a web.config xml sctructured file, It worked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now I need to make it work only when this last folder is not an specific folder, I tried this after a research but no success:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="!^/diretorio/" ignoreCase="true" />
</conditions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the correct code is:

```
<conditions>
     <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/admin/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```